# Javascript to store value until cache is cleared?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following to save a random value in the local storage that will stay until the cache is cleared

```
localStorage['mkey1'] = Math.floor(Math.random()*801);
```

however when on mobile devices this does not work if the user closes the browser app, the cache is deleted. This of course is a result of the problem that the cookies in mobile devices are more like session cookies rather the desired expiration date I set to the cookie.

I have came across different sources like

https://danq.me/2012/04/24/visitor-tracking-without-cookies/
and
http://robertheaton.com/2014/01/20/cookieless-user-tracking-for-douchebags/

but I want to use plain Javascript, no Sinatra.

[image]

Comment: A localstorage is no cookie. And a browser is allowed to decide when it wants to clear it or not - especially on mobile devices memory (even on "disk") is a limited resource.

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage should persist on all browsers until it is cleared, unless the browser doesn't support it; are you using a supported browser on the mobile devices you are testing? http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage